# SSIS proxy problems

Tags: sql-server, ssis, proxy

I have an SSIS job that works when I run it from SSISD, but not when I schedule it through SQL Server Agent Job.  The job brings files over from a mapped drive I have access to our server where it will then load them into our database.  When I run it through the job it fails immediately on on accessing the drive.

I have created a credential using my windows name that has access to the mapped drive.  I have also created a proxy to run the job as.  It is not working with the proxy account.

I have been searching for an answer to this for some time, and have found nothing.  I would love to not have to run the package ever morning manually.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Much appreciated

I am getting three errors from the SSISDB package.

Copy Main from C to Local: Error: File or Directory "\105.102.0\Main" represented by connection Main" does not exist

Main:Error: The file name property is not valid the file name is a device or contains invalid characters.

Main:Error: The file name "\105.102.0\Main" specified in the connection was not valid.

Comment: Please provide any available messages for "It is not working with the proxy account"

Comment: The error from the package in SSISDB is Copy Main from C to Local: Error: File or Directory "\\105.102.0\Main" represented by connection Main" does not exist